# Conditional expectation $E[V|U=u]$

Tags: r, conditional-expectation

Assuming  have two variables $U \sim Uniform(0,1)$ and $V \sim Uniform(0,1)$, I want to calculate the conditional expectation $E[V|U=u]$ in `R`.

Is there a specific function to do that?
What I tried is the following:

```
set.seed(1)
U <- runif(100,0,1)  
V <- runif(100,0,1)
dat <- data.frame(U,V)  # these are my hypothetical data

# conditional expectation E[V|U=u]
expect_V_given_U <- by(data = dat$V, INDICES = dat$U, FUN = mean)
```

Is this the correct way to calculate the conditional expectation?

Answer (score 2):

You don’t have sufficient information. Additionally, you need to know the conditional distribution $p(V|U)$, knowing only the marginal distributions is not enough. Unless you are assuming that they are independent, in such case it’s just $E[V]$.

As about your code, it only does Monte Carlo approximation of $E[V|U]$ rather than doing it directly.